# PHP: Add images to mysql row output blocks in varying positions automatically

Tags: php, mysqli

I am currently creating code blocks to hold up to max 20 names.  I have the code working to create div blocks with increments of 20 names until the data set is empty.

**What I have so far:**

```
function query_groups(){
   //connection string here
  $query = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE group BETWEEN 6 AND 8 ORDER BY 'id' ";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        /* fetch associative array */
        $counter = 1;
        echo '<div id="dynamic-blocks" class="row">';
        echo '<ul class="dynamic-block-items">';
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                 echo "<li>" . $row[0] . "</li>";
                    if($counter % 20 == 0) {
                        //If we are at the end of the dataset, close it.
                        echo '</ul></div><div id="dynamic-blocks" class="row"><ul class="dynamic-block-items">'; 
                    }
                $counter++;
        }
        echo '</ul></div>'; //close all tags.     
return $result;     
}
```

**What I need to do still:**

Insert an image (I have one for each group), into 1 of 3 different positions per block.

Options are:
Beginning of group output
Middle of group output
End of group output

**What the rendered data should look like:**

[image]

Comment: The loop is going to get more complex because you need to do a modulus operation to determine which row you are in in order to set the image location. I would do that first and then add the output for the names.

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard I am working through that now. I can get an image to display in every block.  However, I still cannot get the images to rotate where they fall in the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myimages = array("img1.jpg","img2.jpg");

[...]

$counter = 1;

//like so ?
echo '<div id="divwithmyimage">';
echo '<img src="'.$myimages[$whateverwayIchosetopickone].'" />';
echo '</div>';
//--------

echo '<div id="dynamic-blocks" class="row">';
echo '<ul class="dynamic-block-items">';

[...]
```

As pointed out in the comment to the OP, you need of course to pick a way you like to tell it which image you want for each row. An array of images and a counter may or may not do, you know your environment best.

Edit: Sorry, I was thinking in JS. Array corrected.

More edit: count which row you are in, and fill or empty the "$boxes" with a switch or a few simple ifs. So row 1 (or 0) will see $startbox = "div with the image", $middlebox = "", $endbox = "", and so on for the remaining rows.

```
echo $startbox;
echo '<div id="dynamic-blocks" class="row">';
echo '<ul class="dynamic-block-items">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<li>" . $row[0] . "</li>";
    if($counter % 20 == 0) {
        //If we are at the end of the dataset, close it.
        echo '</ul></div>'.$middlebox.'<div id="dynamic-blocks" class="row"><ul class="dynamic-block-items">'; 
    }
    $counter++;
}
echo '</ul></div>'.$endbox; //close all tags.
```

Comment: Thank you @deg! I am in a time crunch and I really appreciate the direction. Testing out and will report back.

Comment: Thank you! I have the images spilling into the boxes, getting the positioning was the last step. Yay!